# ArtView 10.1" IPS RK66WA ADB device not found

Tags: android, device, adb, detection

I have a ArtView 10.1" IPS for dev some apps

I have installed google driver and all seemm to be ok in device manager i have an ADB interface with no warning

But when i try an "adb.exe devices" the result is empty no line for my tablet.

It's work with my xperia U dunno what to do.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answer... Sad but i found a  way

Check in device manager the Vid of the device

And add a new ligne in C:/User/YOURUSERNAME/.android/adb_usv.ini

who look like 0xABCD

And where ABCD is your VID